# Software to recover/ reset windows 10 admin password

Tags: windows, password-recovery

I forgot the password for my old computer. A quick look on the internet shows that there is a possibility to reset or even recover the password. Unfortunately, all the proposed methods ([ophcrack](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-recover-passwords-using-ophcrack-livecd-2626168),  [Kali Linux](https://www.top-password.com/knowledge/reset-windows-10-password-with-kali-linux.html)) are not working on Windows 10. Other approaches are expensive. Is there any free software that allow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://opensource.com/article/18/3/how-reset-windows-password-linux

Some linux distro come with chntpw
The tutorial show how its done with Fedora, but many other linux bootable ISO can be used.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/Microsoft/
cd /mnt/Microsoft/Windows/System32/config/
sudo chntpw -i SAM
```

Then type 1 (for Edit user data and passwords):
And type your user account name (i.e., Archit-PC in this example) for the username:

Type 1 to clear the user password your user, then quit and save the changes:

Reboot to Windows. If you selected 1 above, you'll see there's no password required to log in. Just click Sign in and you will be logged in: